# PostageApp emails,have they been sent

Tags: php, postageapp

Using PHP how do you get the return state. Whether the message has been received or not. I found this documentation, but it isn't very helpful when using PHP:

http://blog.postageapp.com/tag/php/

I am not sure, but will this be valid:

```
if($this->postageapp->send()==true){ # returns JSON response from the server

//do something, 

}else{

//otherwise

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `var_dump($this->postageapp->send())` in combination with a successful and an unsuccessful attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The send method returns a JSON object whether the call was successful or not. I think PHP always evaluates this return to be true.

Therefore, you need to examine the returned object.

```
$retVal = $this->postageapp->send();
$success = retVal->response->status == 'ok';
```